# Ao pressionar espaço, preciso que o cursor vá até uma posição correta na div editável

Tags: javascript

Preciso muito que quando eu pressione espaço o cursor se posicione de forma correta, ou seja, se digitar test no meio do texto ele fica no meio do texto ao invés de ir para o final. Desde já agradeço

```
<html>
<head>

<script>




function ret_pos(element) 
{
var caretOffset = 0;    
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); 
var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange(); 
preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);  
preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
document.getElementById('po').innerText = caretOffset;
return caretOffset;    
}



function highlight(event,word) 
{               


var tecla = event.keyCode;

if (tecla == 32)
{


//cath the contenteditable element  
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");


//cath the cursor position
var cursor_position=ret_pos(editor);                               





var html_text = editor.innerHTML;


var re = new RegExp(word, 'g');
html_text = html_text.replace(re, '<b>'+word+'</b>');                        

editor.innerHTML=html_text;  


/*agora manda pro fim do texto, mas queria que ficasse onde está, 
  sem o bloco abaixo vai para o início*/

var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(editor);
range.collapse(false);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);


}


}



</script>

<body>
<div id="editor"  onkeypress="highlight(event,'test');" style="position:absolute; display:block; width:50%; height:50%; left:5%; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;" contenteditable>



my text, please insert the word test here and press space.               

</div>


<div  style="position:absolute; width:3%; height:6%; left:36%; top:55%; border-style:solid; border-width:0.3px;">
<text id="po">...</text>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: E o que seria de **forma correta**??

Comment: O cursor ir para a posição que estava antes da substituição, ret_pos informa esta posição. Obrigado